# What is the sum of all integers between 15 and 415 that are divisible by 7? - explain solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, proof-explanation

Question: Using Sigma notation and discrete math rules, calculate the sum of all integers between 15 and 415 that are divisible by 7.

I have a given solution for this but I don't quite understand it and I was wondering if someone could explain.

The first number is 7×⌈(15+1)/7⌉ = 7×3 = 21 and the last number is 7×⌊(415-1)/7⌋ = 7×59 = 413.

The sum of all integers between 15 and 415 that are divisible by 7 is then:

7 × [k = 3 to 59]∑k

= 7 × ([k = 1 to 59]∑k - [k = 1 to 2]∑k)

= 7 × (59×60 - 2×3)/2

= 7 × 1767

= 12369

I don't understand where 7x3 and 7x59 came from in the calculation above. (15+1)/7 is 2.28 so should it not be 7x2.28 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers between $15$ and $415$ are
$$
16, 17, 18, \ldots, 412, 413, 414
$$
Among these, the numbers which are divisible by $7$ are
$$
21, 28, 35, \ldots, 399, 406, 413
$$
Writing these explicitly as multiples of $7$, we get
$$
3\cdot 7, 4\cdot 7, 5\cdot 7, \ldots, 57\cdot 7, 58\cdot 7, 59\cdot 7
$$
We are interested in the sum of all these numebrs. This is where $3\cdot 7$ and $59\cdot 7$ comes from. The formulas that are written there,
$$
\left\lceil\frac{15 + 1}{7}\right\rceil\cdot 7 = 21\\
\text{and}\\
\left\lfloor\frac{415-1}{7}\right\rfloor\cdot 7 = 413
$$
is just an algebraic way to express the same idea.

Comment: But 414 isn't technically divisible by 7 though is it? It gives a decimal value.

Comment: @herondale yeah, sorry. That was a mistake. Meant to be $413$.

Answer (score 1):

$7\cdot3$ it's the first and $7\cdot59$ it's the last needed number between $15$ and $415$.

Also, $$\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ and from here
$$7\sum_{k=3}^{59}k=7\left(\frac{59\cdot60}{2}-1-2\right)=12369.$$

Comment: sorry could you explain how the first formula got translated into the second? I don't understand where the -1 and -2 came from

Comment: @herondale Just $\sum\limits_{k=3}^{59}k=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{59}k-\sum\limits_{k=1}^2k=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{59}k-1-2.$

Comment: @herondale $\sum\limits_{k=\color{red}{1}}^{59} k = \color{red}{1}+\color{red}{2}+\sum\limits_{k=\color{blue}{3}}^{59}k$.  So, the sum starting from $k=3$ is the same as the sum starting from $k=1$ apart from the case where $k=1$ and $k=2$.  The $-1$ and $-2$ are there to account for the difference.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more to add to the conversation, the line you seem to be confused by is the one that begins with this:

"The first number is $7\times \lceil(15+1)/7\rceil$"

You are correct that the expression on the right simplifies to $(15+1)/7$ and so the entire expression simplifies to $7\times \lceil \frac{16}{7}\rceil$ which is approximately $7\times \lceil 2.28\rceil$... (*note that $\frac{16}{7}$ is not precisely equal to $2.28$, only approximately equal.  Only use equals signs for equality!*)

What you seem to be forgetting is that $7\times \lceil 2.28\rceil$ is *not* the same thing as $7\times 2.28$.  The bars you see there represent the **ceiling function** which  "rounds up" whatever is put in between the bars to the next highest integer (*if what is put in is an integer already it doesn't change it*).

For example $\lceil 4.2\rceil = 5$ and $\lceil 2\rceil = 2$.  Negative arguments here, remember that "up" means to the right on the number line, not just larger in terms of absolute value, so $\lceil -13.57\rceil = -13$.

The expression we are interested then continues to be simplified as $7\times \lceil \frac{16}{7}\rceil \color{grey}{(\approx 7\times \lceil 2.28\rceil)} = 7\times 3 = 21$

This was all just a fancy way of finding what integer strictly larger than $15$ was the next multiple of $7$.  This could have been done strictly by inspection, remembering our multiples of seven and knowing that $21$ is the next multiple of seven after $15$.

Answer (score 0):

The first multiple of $7$ between $15$ and $415$ is $21$, i.e. $7 \times 3$. The last multiple of $7$ between between $15$ and $415$ is $413$, i.e. $7 \times 59$.

So you have to sum the multiples of $7$ between $7 \times 3$ and $7 \times 59$...

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\lceil  x \rceil $ is the "ceiling" function.  It means to round UP to the nearest integer.  The notation $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the "floor" function.  It means to round DOWN to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

Multiples of $7$ look like $1 \times 7$, $2 \times 7$, $3 \times 7$, $4 \times 7$, and so on. $2 \times 7 = 14 < 15$ and $3 \times 7 = 21 > 15$ so we can be sure that the multiples of $7$ greater than $15$ start at $21$.

The number $x$ such that $x \times 7 = 15$ is, unsurprisingly, $\frac{15}{7}$. The first whole number $>x$ is $\lceil \frac{15+1}{7} \rceil$ since if we didn't add $1$ and $x$ were already a whole number we would get $x$ (which isn't $>x$).

So doing $\lceil \frac{15+1}{7} \rceil$ is just working out that $\frac{15}{7} = 2.28$ so the next whole number is $3$, so that's where we should start our multiples of $7$ from, and the first one will be $$21 = 3 \times 7 = \lceil \frac{15+1}{7} \rceil \times 7.$$

The same idea works for the multiples of $7$ less than $415$.